# Possible to sort via two time stamps and display same row twice

Tags: mysql, timetable, time-tracking

I'm looking at creating a time table solution.
I have a task sheet that looks like

> Area 1 item 1 startTime endTime
>   Area 1 item1 startTime endTime

I wish to create a display where I can view what even is happening next, either endTime or startTime

i.e.

> Newcastle reel 16:45 18:45
>   Newcastle reel2 17:45 19:45

would output

> Newcastle reel 16:45
>   Newcastle reel 17:45
>   Newcastle reel 18:45
>   Newcastle reel 19:45

More so, I would like to detect if the time is a startTime or an endTime would I have to enter two rows for each activity (time,area,item, start|end). I can make the interface to the creation of two rows. I just wondered if there was a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your existing schema, this query should work:

```
SELECT * FROM
((SELECT Area, Item, startTime AS eventTime FROM tasks)
UNION
(SELECT Area, Item, endTime FROM tasks)) AS t
ORDER BY eventTime
```

Basically, you're selecting all the start times, then the end times, then sorting them.

Comment: Totally forgot about UNION. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an event table with

- id
- time
- type (start or end)
- event details id

and an event details table with

- id
- description

You can then do `select time, type, description from event left join event_details on event.details_id = event_details.id order by time`.

This should give you the desired output.

If you want to get output with start AND end times in each row, then you need to do something like `select event_details.description, min(time) as start, max(time) as end from event left join event_details on event.details_id = event_details.id group by event_details.description`.